# Confusion over branch creation in git

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-checkout

After making a few changes to branch `master` I decided to work from a new branch. I did `git checkout -b new_branch_name` and a new branch was created and checked out. `git status` showed the changes I had made to `master`.

I was curious if my changes were now on both branches (`master` and `new_branch_name`) or just `new_branch_name`. So I checked out `master` and noticed my changes were there as well. So I reverted those changes with `git checkout -- fileThatChanged`. The changes were indeed gone from `master`.

Unfortunately checking out `new_branch_name` and running `git status` showed my changes were reverted from that branch as well.

I'd like to understand what happened and how can I avoid this in the future.

One solution is to just create/checkout a new branch before starting work.

Comment: The thing you need to remember is that branches point to commits, and commits represent snapshots of the whole work tree. A checked-out branch is just the one where the next commit will go. (The work tree is completely separate from commits, and the index is a staging area between the two.) If you'd like a wordy explanation of the core ideas of Git, you could try [The Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had never committed your changes to either branch.  That is, if you did this:

```
$ git status
```

And saw something like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   myfile.txt
#
```

The changes to "myfile.txt" do not "exist" on any branch -- they are only in your local working copy.  They don't end up on a branch until you have comitted them to a repository.

If at this point I were to type:

```
$ git checkout myfile.txt
```

This would obliterate my changes (and return the file to whatever it looked like in the last commit on my current branch).

If I wanted to commit these changes on a new branch, I might do something like this:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch_name
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m "made some changes"
```

Comment: Sounds like committing the changes to the new branch immediately after creating/checking-out the new branch would solve this.

Comment: That is largely what I was trying to indicate in that final example.

Answer (score 3):

The index is shared amongst all branches. As it the local working tree. 
It represents what will be committed, without assuming in what branch it will be committed.
But that means it you revert a change (ie remove it from the index or from the local workspace), it will be reverted no matter what branch you are in.

See also:

- "[what does the git index EXACTLY contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-exactly-contains)".
- a [Git file transition diagram](http://ebixio.com/blog/2009/11/05/git-file-transition-diagram/)

[image: git file transition]

Comment: The index doesn't come into play here.  Files end up in the index after a `git add` operation.  Changes to files that have been neither added nor committed are not in the index.

Comment: @larsks: you are right regarding the checkout -F (only the working tree is affected). But I was editing my answer as you were commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Modified changes in your working directory / index ( what you see in git status ) are not linked to a branch but are common. So when you switch branches, the changes will still be in the new branch. If you undo the changes, that will be seen when you switch branches. You should either commit or stash before changing branch.

Answer (score 1):

As larsks says, you did not have these changes committed.

If you are looking to switch branches while remembering your working copy, you must use `git stash`.

When you are done, you can use `git stash pop` to restore your in-process working directory.