# Git commands in a batch file ran through VSTS throwing an error

Tags: git, batch-file, github, azure-devops

I have cloned remote GitHub repository into my Build Server.
A build definition in VSTS generated a file as build artifact. I copy that file into local github repository in build server through a powershell script task in VSTS.
I want to run Git commands to push this new build artifact file from local github repository to remote GitHub repository.
I have stored batch file with Git commands on build server.
When a build runs on VSTS, I try to invoke batch file residing in build server through a "Command Line Script" VSTS task.

Command Line Script:

```
cd "batch file path"
GitCommands.bat
```

Now I keep getting errors related to git commands in batch file. Below is an example.

**Note: I am trying to push a single file directly to github repository using git commands in batch file.**

```
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9089221Z On branch master
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9090417Z Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9166091Z 
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9180427Z Untracked files:
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9205244Z   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9224271Z 
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9298112Z    filename.ipa
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9316134Z 
2018-08-30T20:17:07.9457726Z nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
2018-08-30T20:17:10.4572412Z fatal: Unable to write new index file
2018-08-30T20:17:10.4614209Z file added
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5106172Z On branch master
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5107096Z Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5131465Z 
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5145982Z Untracked files:
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5184825Z    filename.ipa
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5204032Z 
2018-08-30T20:17:10.5280428Z nothing added to commit but untracked files present
2018-08-30T20:17:38.9087093Z Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Batch file content:

```
*cd to github loval repository

git status

git add .

echo file added

git commit -m "Adding ipa file to the repository through VSTS automated build"

git push origin master*
```

Comment: It's due to some lock [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064513/git-fatal-unable-to-write-new-index-file) the solution is

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **PowerShell task** to replace the Command Line task. The PowerShell script should be:

```
cd \path\to\local\github\repo
git status
git add .
echo "file added"
git commit -m "Adding ipa file to the repository through VSTS automated build"
git push https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame master
```

Then you should commit and push the new added file successful to github repo.

**Note:** You need to provide credential (username and password) when pushing changes to github.