# What's the difference between git diff and gif diff-index

Tags: git

When I want to get git diff files, I found someone use

```
git diff-index --cached  --diff-filter=AM --name-only  HEAD
```

and if I use

```
git diff --cached --diff-filter=AM --name-only  HEAD
```

can get the same result.
So what's the difference between `git diff` and `git diff-index`?
When you must use `git diff-index` but not `git diff`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`git diff-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) is a diff against the index or working tree:

> Compares the content and mode of the blobs found in a tree object with the corresponding tracked files in the working tree, or with the corresponding paths in the index

[`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is more versatile and can compare two files, or two commits, or (like diff-index) a tree and the index.

In your case, a `diff HEAD` would indeed diff HEAD against the index, which `diff-index` does too.

---

Warning: "[`git diff --cached`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/671eaaac0caac4826d6182bd5a57c9e0a8ed7a27/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> codepath did not fill the necessary stat information for a file when fsmonitor knows it is clean, and ended up behaving as if it is not clean, which has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 6a044a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a044a20480a8ef56f7ddb8142f660ca01a3391e) (11 Sep 2023) by [Josip Sokcevic (`sokac`)](https://github.com/sokac).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 671eaaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/671eaaac0caac4826d6182bd5a57c9e0a8ed7a27), 20 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff-lib`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a044a20480a8ef56f7ddb8142f660ca01a3391e): fix `check_removed` when fsmonitor is on
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josip Sokcevic</sup>

> [`git diff-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a044a20480a8ef56f7ddb8142f660ca01a3391e/Documentation/git-diff-index.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index))</sup> may return incorrect deleted entries when fsmonitor is used in a repository with git submodules.
> This can be observed on Mac machines, but it can affect all other supported platforms too.
>
> If fsmonitor is used, `stat *st` is not initialized if `cache_entry` has `CE_FSMONITOR_VALID` set.
> But, there are three call sites that rely on stat afterwards, which can result in incorrect results.
>
> This change partially reverts [commit 4f3d6d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3d6d026176a48991c4e5ff95c8db583af38148) ("`fsmonitor`: skip lstat deletion check during `git diff-index`", 2021-03-17, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/858119f6d78d13050d446b5d56445ad1e5432082) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26c4f98ffda512bc0731c4bd13e22338137e9a7c)).

Comment: what is the index?

Comment: @Will the index is where you prepare your next commit. Linux Torvalds, when making Git back in 2005, needed a tool where he could add multiple changes while ignoring others, in order to prepare the next Linux code commit. For more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309

Comment: git diff-index is not always against the index. As the documentation says: "Compare a tree to the working tree or index"

Comment: @Droopycom Agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

diff-index is a lower level operation that does less but is much faster because it doesn't look at the content, it only checks metadata like timestamps. Only Linux you can verify this with something like:

```
  strace -f -e file -o diff-index.log git diff-index HEAD
  wc diff-index.log
  less diff-index.log
```

Forget about diff-index unless you have some git performance problem to solve.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit

https://public-inbox.org/git/loom.20160331T143733-916@post.gmane.org/

Answer (score 3):

After investigating the difference between these two commands, I have found starange behavior:

Looks like `git diff-index` is sensitive if the file has changed but the content is not. while `git diff` is not sensitive in this case.

In other words if you want to know if a file is NOT changed but you don't care the timestamp of the last-change was changed, use `git diff`.

- Note: I'm not sure I'm correct here.

Comment: https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/3Xf875jB/diff-on-touched-files-bug-or-feature talks about this peculiarity of `git diff-index`

Comment: This is correct. Can be verified using `touch foo && git diff-index HEAD -- foo`. This will be reset by something like `git status`, see `touch foo && git status > /dev/null && git diff-index HEAD -- foo`