# Why is the command 'git diff-index --check --cached $against --' outputting usage information?

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a precommit hook to prevent committing merge conflicts accidentally... basically cancelling the commit when it includes `>>>>`. I've found multiple viable-looking approaches, but I am wondering why the "official" approach is not working (trying to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150330/752916 which refers to https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.26.0/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample#L49).  When I execute this command, I am presented with usage information (see below) instead of an error. I expected something like this `leftover conflict marker` because I have a test conflict in my codebase. I am not looking for alternatives, those are readily available on SO already. I just want to know why this command doesn't work.

```
$ git diff-index --check --cached $against --
usage: git diff-index [-m] [--cached] [<common-diff-options>] <tree-ish> [<path>...]
common diff options:
  -z            output diff-raw with lines terminated with NUL.
  -p            output patch format.
```

#### Debugging info:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.25.0.windows.1
```

I tried this in Git Bash and Windows Powershell, same result in both.

Comment: What does `$against` expand to here?

Comment: @torek $against appears to be an empty string. `echo "Against is $against"` in my githook outputs `Against is `

Comment: OK, that would be the problem then: `git diff-index` *requires* a `<tree-ish>` argument, as indicated by the syntax. Which tree would you like to diff the index against?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, $against needs to be a tree-ish. But, I don't believe I am required to set that value myself - git should do it for me. If git on windows has the restriction that `$against` is not available, then is a git hook with this command impossible on Windows despite it being the official example? Or does it just involve an extra step of setting $against to the right tree-ish? If so, what should the right tree-ish be?

Comment: Did you copy the entire script from `https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.26.0/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample`? `against` is set at line 12 or line 15, depending on other conditions. If you copied only line 47, `against`—which is a *shell* variable, not a Git one—is not going to be set.

Comment: @torek Oh wow, you're totally right. I am blind. If you copy that to the answer I will give you the green check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, the basic issue here was copying some, but not enough, of the script at https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.26.0/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample.  With shell variable `against` unset, `$against` expanded to nothing at all, leaving `git diff-index` with no `<tree-ish>` argument.

Copying enough setup from the script should fix the problem.