# What are the "lindex", "rindex" and "wtindex" files generated by git difftool?

Tags: git, git-index, git-difftool

When I run:

```
git difftool -d
```

It creates a temporary directory containing the files to be shown in the diff. The structure looks like this:

```
tmpdir/
  left/
    file1
  lindex
  right/
    file1
  rindex
```

The "left" and "right" directories are clear. But what are the "lindex" and "rindex" files? What do they contain? How can I view them? Sometimes there's no "rindex" but a "wtindex" file instead.

Comment: Probably need to mention (and tag) what tool you are actually using as `git difftool`... Then consult the documentation for that tool...

Comment: When you pass "-d", the `git-difftool` command itself generates this directory structure before passing control to the diff tool itself. So this really is a `git-difftool` question.

Comment: @twalberg it's in the `git-difftool.perl` [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.0.1/git-difftool.perl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They represent [indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309), generated by [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) in [`git-difftool.perl#L224-L248`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f92e5ff3cdc813de8ef5327fd4bad492fb7d6c9/git-difftool.perl#L224-L248).

- `lindex` represents LOCAL: A temporary file containing the contents of the file on the current branch.
- `rindex` represents REMOTE: A temporary file containing the contents of the file to be merged.
- `wtindex` represented MERGED (working tree): the result of the merge in progress

Those indexes are updated [using `--index-info`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_--index-info) in order to facilitate the diff between any locale modification you will be doing for each file, and the three versions mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to dump the contents of these files using [this script](https://gist.github.com/sriranggd/1144775). At the end of the day, they don't seem that interesting. There's nothing in them that you couldn't get from inspecting the files in the "left" and "right" directories.