# Getting a fatal error in git for multiple stage entries

Tags: git

Using Git version 2.2.0 with unity game engine on OS X, and wanted to commit my code.  I added everything and did not get an error message.  then commit -m , and got this error message:

```
fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file 'Assets/Prefabs/Resources'
```

Not noticing it I pushed, that didn't give an error message, in fact said `Everything up-to-date`
So I checked bitbucket (where the repo is held) and it didn't show my commit.  so I checked my local log and that also does not show my commit.

I've looked into google for an answer... and nothing. what is this error? and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of git, or tool are you using?  There has been a recent thread on the developers list about improving the checking for multiple stage entries. http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git

Comment: Sounds likely that the extra checking in 2.2.0 may be involved. "Ensure unmerged entries are removed" 12 Aug by Jaime Soriano Pastor, may be one thread to start with.

Comment: so why does this happen?

Comment: just make a dummy edit to the the said file and 'commit and sync' .

Comment: Note: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919644/6309

Comment: See also [What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-contain-exactly) as well as [What's the difference between HEAD, working tree and index, in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

The first workaround, which seems to work with recent versions of Git (2.3+, Q2+ 2015) is mentioned in [grant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2403277/grant)'s [more up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261818/6309):

1. Delete the index

   ```
   $ rm .git/index
   ```
2. Add all

   ```
   $ git add -A
   ```
3. Commit

   ```
   $ git commit -a
   ```

---

Original answer (late 2014)
The usual workaround is to:

- clone again the remote repo into a new local repo
- add the changes from the first repo to the second one:

  ```
  $ cd /patH/to/second/cloned/repo
  $ git --work-tree=/path/to/first/repo add .
  ```

You can see this error message in [`read-cache.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9abc44b681a669c67d071d858c8aad21f65a0956/read-cache.c#L1484), discussed in this patch ("[`read-cache.c`: Ensure unmerged entries are removed](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-read-cache-c-Ensure-unmerged-entries-are-removed-td7616733i40.html) "), and introduced in the [Git 2.2 commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15999d0be8179fb7a2e6eafb931d25ed65df50aa).
Since this is so recent, it is possible that *downgrading* Git to 2.1 would be enough to not be affected by that patch.

The [OP Daniel Toebe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371285/daniel-toebe) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries/27481661#comment43579939_27481661):

> The issue happened on my macbook, which decided to fail on me, and another computer mishap put me way behind on my projects.

Comment: @sharpner it is possible that it is a bug, or a side-effect of that patch in your case.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... The issue happened on my macbook, which decided to fail on me, and another computer mishap put me way behind on my projects.

Comment: @DanielToebe good feedback. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I just ran into the same, after an attempt to `git commit -c sha`

Comment: This is still a problem for me and trying the workaround did not restore my uncommitted local changes. I got this when I did a git add

Comment: @doorfly what version of Git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: @VonC mac 2.2.1. Also the full message is this "fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file src/test". If I recall correctly I think there was a file in staging: src/test/org/etc/etc/File.java. Then I got this error when I git add another file: src/test/resources/etc/Resource.json.

Comment: @doorfly just in case, can you check if the issue persists with Git 2.3.0?

Comment: Not sure how to do this with homebrew. 2.2.1 is the latest.

Comment: @VonC I've just experienced exactly this problem. I've used your suggestion to get my local changes committed up to the remote repository. But do I now have to abandon my original cloned repo,  or perhaps delete the .git directory in it and "attach" (wrong term, I'm sure) that cloned repository again to the remote repository?

Comment: @rcd: that cloned repo is attached to the remote repo since it is a clone of the remote repo. As for the first repo, it can be ignored.

Comment: @VonC Ok, thanks. Out of interest, because the original cloned repo is within my Eclipse workspace, I tried seeing if I could recover that original cloned repo anyway by deleting the `.git` directory and running `git init` and `git remote add origin <path to remote repo>`. In the end I had to delete the local versions of the files there before I could pull from the remote, so I might have just copied them in from local clone 2 ...

Comment: @rdc yes, it is best to reset the Eclipse environment, importing again the new git repo instead of trying fiddling with an existing one.

Comment: This should be the last resort. I would suggest anyone who faces this issue to try out @grant's response http://stackoverflow.com/a/29261818/1017056. It worked for me.

Comment: For any interested, this happened to me because i was accidentally editing a file in my .git folder instead of the file itself.

Comment: be careful while performing steps given in this answer. When I executed $ rm .git/index it shown all files as deleted files in the project. If you are in a production project take caution before copy pasting these commands and hitting enter!!!

Comment: Deleting index file is not a solution. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Emd it is best to ask a new question, with your git version, and why deleting the index is not an option in your case.

Comment: @VonC I have posted a new question. Please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974245/fatal-error-in-git-multiple-stage-entries-for-merged-file

Answer (score 167):

I believe I encountered this issue because I added and committed changes and then deleted a file that I had just committed. If this sounds similar to your case, I recommend following the below to save re-cloning and manually adding in your changes.

I was able to fix this issue by deleting the .git/index file in my repository, similar to what @slider suggested (I believe he mistyped the path).

```
rm .git/index
```

Then I had to add and commit my local changes again

```
git add -A
git commit -m "..."
```

I was then able to push remotely.

What is the git index and how is it relevant?

[What’s The Deal With The Git Index?](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/whats-the-deal-with-the-git-index/)

> The git “index” is where you place files you want committed to the git repository.
>
> Before you “commit” (checkin) files to the git repository, you need to first place the files in the git “index”.

I believe that by deleting this file, git will re-index the repo, create a new one and you're good to go. It solves this problem because the local repository is re-indexed without the file I deleted that caused all the fuss.

Edit: It seems like this is Mac related (based on comments) so if it helps I'm on OSX 10.10 and git version 2.3.4 installed through brew.

Comment: Yay, this worked and thank you for the explanation. One caveat here is before you do this is to stash or move or delete any files that you did not have added the current default change list. They will get sucked back in with the `git add -A`

Comment: @Kirby I agree it is indeed more manageable than my answer in your case. +1  to grant.

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment on your answer as I didn't think it was fair since  I didn't actually try your way :).

Comment: Confirm this on Mac OS X Yosemite. Happened while working in Android Studio, though there were no specific reproducible scenario..

Comment: This should be the correct answer because it works and it has a better explanation. This just happened to me as well.

Comment: Worked for me also. Adding version control root in IntelliJ borked it but rm'ing the git index worked fine. Thanks for the explanation @grant.

Comment: I also had this problem when IntelliJ was running in the background while I was making some modifications with vim. I think there was a race condition in `git`. (Actually, I think there are a lot of them.) Closing IntelliJ, removing the index, and re-committing my work worked just fine.

Comment: Solved my problem with source tree too.

Comment: I got this problem on OSX today, git version 2.2.1. I have a suspicion it's because I committed with a comment like this:  -m "something something 'comment in quotes' something".  Nested quotes. I think this was the first time I did that. Can that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: After rm .git/index, all files of my project where listed with a delete status (using git status). So, I had to type a git reset before continuing with git add / git commit. Cheers.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For me, this seems to involve committing thousands of files up - which I don't think I'm going to go ahead with.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 getting this error - not Mac related

Answer (score 120):

### For project

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

after deleting index you need to recreate it by git reset

### For submodule:

Go to main project folder

```
rm .git/modules/your_project_structure/index
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: The git reset after the removal of the index totally nailed it. Thanks! If you don't reset every file will be new to the index, so has to be added. Resetting will rebuild the index it seems. Even though I don't understand how git can rebuild the index, without an index?

Comment: @JosFaber Because index is not commit history. Actually it is "redundant" helper structure. See http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/7_the_git_index.html
So it can be completely rebuild comparing working tree and HEAD.
And that's exactly what git reset does. Man page says: ... reset copy entries from <tree-ish> to the index ...

Comment: Thank you!  Without the git reset, it wanted me to re-add all of the files already in the repository.

Comment: I use sourcetree on my mac. I manually deleted the .git/index, then selected the last good commit, right clicked, selected reset master (in my case) to this comment - then chose the mixed option which leaves my work in a good state. I was then able to do a commit of my current work and everything is healthy now.

Comment: The cleanest and the fastest way!

Comment: Thank a lot, this two step solution worked for me perfectly. I didn't want to re-commit and go through the complications as mentioned in the other answers. Happened to me on Mac El Capitan, Android Studio and SourceTree. Now I am back in business :)

Comment: I really didn't want to commit again so this solution worked perfectly. It should be the accepted answer imo. I think I witnessed a conflict between GitKraken and VS Code which seemed corrupt .git/index.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 I created a simple .bat file that did a `cd .git` followed by `git reset` in the folder holding the solution file. Before running the .bat file with a mouse click,, I renamed `index` to `indexxx` by hand. After renaming `index`, the VS git plug-in showed I had to add all files. After running .bat file to do reset, only the changed files showed and `index` file was recreated in `.git`. I can now do sync and see only changed files.

Answer (score 29):

You can remove Git index file from your project. In the root of your project, run the following command:

```
rm .git/index
```

After that git it work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please flesh out this answer with more details.

Comment: Did not work for me ```rm: /.git/index: No such file or directory``` Mac OSX Yosemite; git 2.3.4 installed through homebrew

Comment: @grant You have to remove the slash at the beginning. (`rm .git/index` in your git directory).

Comment: @ChristophLSA thank you - I answered with a description of what this action does to provide clarity. Can this answer be updated to to reflect the proper path and and inform users what the action does?

Comment: I know why this works.  The problem is caused by a corrupted index.  I ran into this problem when I corrupted the index by modifying code in IntelliJ while writing a commit message in the command line.  Deleting the index does not destroy your changes, it simply unstages them.

Comment: I submitted an edit to fix the path and add a little more detail, but @grant's answer above is the better one, and should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: This is the best answer to my mind, no committing thousands of files and just works instantly.

Answer (score 3):

I try a different solution and it works for me. Below are my options

```
#cd .git
#rm index
#cd ..
#git add .
```

Comment: as @farincz said , you need to recreate index again by calling `git reset` otherwise it gives you `fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD' `.

Answer (score 1):

## If this happens in a submodule

The index file is located inside the parent `.git` directory:

```
.git/modules/your_project_structure/index
```

In a submodule, there are no directories named `.git` (at least in the project I'm working on), there's only a `.git` file which tells you (and git) where to look for the git directory of that project.

## Git status shows changes that I didn't make

After removing the index files, and doing a `git reset`, I found myself facing lots of inexplicable changes and a hard reset wasn't helping.

**Warning** you'll lose all your changes, so commit them and push before continuing.

The index seemed corrupted, so I removed it with the following commands.

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error with the Github Desktop Client (OSX). All I did was quit the app and reopened and then it started working.