# git fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file

Tags: git, macos

Git throws an error:

```
fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file
```

I've been on the side ([Getting a fatal error in git for multiple stage entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries)) and read the workaround:

```
cd /patH/to/second/cloned/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/first/repo add .
```

Now, the changes can be queried via status, but after that what i have to do now? When I use git add, then everything back to last version. All changes are gone. The changes were removed and my new repo has the old status again. How can i put all change to the new repository?
I use git version 2.2.0 on OS X 10.10.

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries

Comment: This question was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolved this problem:

In your terminal, type this:

```
rm .git/index (press enter key)
git add -A (press enter key)
git commit -m "your commit instruction"
```