# How to recover from "unordered stage entries in index" error in git

Tags: git, git-svn

I've just upgraded my `git` from `2.0.5` to `2.3.6`, and I'm now unable to run `git svn fetch` in one of my repositories:

```
$ git svn fetch
fatal: unordered stage entries in index
write-tree: command returned error: 128
```

`git status` shows a few untracked files but is otherwise clean.

I located the change where this check was introduced, with the summary "[read_index_from(): catch out of order entries when reading an index file](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=15999d0be8179fb7a2e6eafb931d25ed65df50aa)" (first appearing in `2.2.0`), and some [mailing list discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-read-cache-c-Ensure-unmerged-entries-are-removed-td7616733i40.html) of it that says among other things:

> I think we have been discussing how to protect broken index file left
>   by tools other people wrote, so I wouldn't be so surprised if our
>   current toolset does not let you recreate certain breakages ;-)

I don't recall running any other tools on this repo; it doesn't do much day-to-day other than a long series of `git svn fetch`es.  (But it's been around for a couple of years so who knows.)

At any rate, what can I do to recover from this situation?  I tried to locate a path with multiple index entries like this but got no results:

```
$ git ls-files -s | cut -f 2-100 | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '^[ \t]*1 '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what can I do to recover from this situation?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481661/3161761

something like this

```
rm .git/index
git add -A
```

Comment: I've long since discarded the repo that suffered from this problem, so I can't say for sure if this would've fixed it.  But it's at least a good lead, so I'm accepting it.  Thanks!