# Fatal Error in Git: Multiple Stage Entries For Merged File

Tags: git, bash

I am working on a production project of my company. Previously I created a stash with some changes. Then when I tried to apply my stash, it created conflict. I tried to reset all changes from Visula Studio by clicking undo in every file. Then when I tried to show status from git bash I got following error message.

```
fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file 'Server/InternalService/Web.config'
```

I know solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries), but as I am working on a production project, so I can not delete my git index file and commit everything again. Is there any better solution?

I am using `git version 2.10.1.windows.1` and `Visual Studio 2013`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries

Comment: Don't forget to add the versions (of your OS, Git, visual studio, ...)

Comment: @yorammi, I have mentioned that I already checked that question, but that is not helping me.

Comment: Why not? It should only commit the changes to the last repository version.