# What is the 3rd column of the output of git show-index?

Tags: git

When I use `git show-index` I get something like this:

```
12 3efc399e3f684061ef13c5b7dfde66342ef23033 (44b2e14e)
218 53f4215e537f351457713ad4f18d6e5d5dedf333 (480e84f1)
422 b532ec8e8e38c52002e953c878010391245eaa84 (bbaa1b63)
625 bb4359ded039eefe9fab5c99f196c67ba1a9493e (68e4b84f)
```

According to the man page, the first two values are the offset in the packfile and the sha1 of each object. But what's that third value in parentheses? I can't find anything about that.

Comment: Does the third column show up for every entry?  If it didn't, I could see it being the base for deltification, as in git verify-pack.  Let me see if I can figure it out from the source. ... Well, if I'm reading the source right, that third column is a CRC of the object whose hash is the second column.

Comment: @Joe This question is about packfile indexes, not the git index (aka staging area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with [version two packfiles](http://schacon.github.io/git/technical/pack-format.txt), this is the CRC32 of the packfile data.

It's not the CRC32 of the *object* - that would be redundant, with the SHA1 value right there - it's the CRC32 of the actual compressed (or deltafied) packfile data.  This allows you to read the data out of the packfile and validate it *without* uncompressing it or applying the deltas to reconstitute the full object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corresponding snippet from `show-index.c`:

```
        printf("%" PRIuMAX " %s (%08"PRIx32")\n",
               (uintmax_t) offset,
               sha1_to_hex(entries[i].sha1),
               ntohl(entries[i].crc));
```

That makes it look like the third column is a CRC of the object whose hash is the second column.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) brings more details on `git show-index` format output, especially in the context of the [index V2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309).

It points out that [commit 32637cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32637cdf4a6a8d806feaa6b018bc4e4c7e2eb366) (`show-index.c`: learn about index v2,
2007-04-09, Git v1.5.2) changed the output format of `show-index` to include the object CRC32 but didn't update the documentation.

See [commit fb3010c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb3010c31fdaa00ae91152431c3da7e300daf848) (28 May 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Jeff King -- `peff` --](https://github.com/peff) in [commit fb3010c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb3010c31fdaa00ae91152431c3da7e300daf848), 28 May 2018)</sup>

The [`git show-index` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa82bb70d9ef3acb6a47cddfb38a7b0ca40ac362/Documentation/git-show-index.txt#L17-L37) now includes:

> The output consists of one object per line, with each line containing two or three space-separated columns:
>
> - the first column is the offset in bytes of the object within the corresponding packfile,
> - the second column is the object id of the object,
> - if the index version is 2 or higher, the third column contains the CRC32 of the object data