# What does "Checking out files out of the index" mean?

Tags: git, version-control

While I am learning about `git checkout -- file1.txt`, I came across [this link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation) related to argument disambiguation. In this manual, what does  "Checking out files out of the index" mean?

Comment: For that, you need to understand what index is. The index is a single, large, binary file in `<baseOfRepo>/.git/index`, which lists all files in the current branch. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git) SO question out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between HEAD, working tree and index, in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the new [`git restore` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), available from Git 2.23 (August 2019), and [which replaces the old confusing git checkout command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

With `git restore --staged`, you would explicitly restore a file content [from the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/6309) (see also "[What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309)")

Answer (score 0):

The index lists the repo content for a work tree path (it's an index after all, names and pointers to related content), and it's got a timestamp so Git can quickly check whether the work tree content has changed.

So when you `git add`, Git adds what you added to the repo (you can do this directly with `git hash-object -w`) and updates the index entry to point to the added content (you can do this directly with `git update-index --cacheinfo` or `--index-info`).

Checkout from the index reads the index entry, then reads that content from the repo's object db into the work tree.