# How to undo a diff chunk in git with cli？

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, diff

There is a feature in vscode that can help undo changes to a region of code

[image]

I'm guessing it has something to do with the chunks that git diff generates.

But I didn't find out how to do this with git cli. I'm very curious about the mechanics of this feature. It seems to me that it implements an undo operation that is more granular than a file.

I'd really like to know if this has anything to do with diff or git or any other tool behind it.

Comment: In general, one uses the `-p` arguments to operate on individual patches/hunks. You can, for example, use `git checkout committish -- filespec` to get the files you intend into the state you want, then use `git reset -p` to unstage the changes you don't want to commit (as an inverse of `git add -p`, which lets you stage only individual changes).

Comment: (which is all to say that this is very well-documented functionality, and I'm unclear on how it could have been missed if you'd looked at the `git add` manual).

Comment: As for the _mechanics_, what's unclear about them? It's obvious that when you use `git add` with no further arguments it stores _the current state_ of the file, instead of just adding the file of a list of things to commit (in which case future changes would always unconditionally always be committed). That tells you that `git add` must have a way to store a state that's distinct from the working tree's contents (the "staging area"), and once you know it exists, _of course_ you can store constructed states ("this file plus this specific diff") in that area.

Comment: ...the mechanics are the same as everything else; you've got trees that refer to objects by hash. That the contents never existed in exactly that form in the working tree is irrelevant, as long as you have it in the hash-addressed store.

Comment: Closely related: [Commit only part of a file's changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-files-changes-in-git)

Comment: As for the mechanics, see [What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-contain-exactly) (the "index" and the "staging area" are one and the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One command for it is simply use `git restore --staged -p <path/to/file>` to unstage changes in patches (unstaging 'hunk' as per this command), as is better commented already on your post in a series of comments by @[Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).

As for this background for this Git chunk undone with VS Code, there are a set of commands displayed for it:
[image]
(Image with test file paths hidden :)

Command starting with git for-each-ref and using --ignore-case is what seems most relevant for this purpose. Of course, these commands also include other Git status sync and processing done by it.

The exact commands can always be checked in this Output tab (accessible next to Terminal option) with Git chosen in the dropdown.